# Removing non-used default font from flutter projects

Tags: flutter, material-ui, roboto

If I prefer to use only custom or google fonts in my Flutter project, will my build still include default ones? (Roboto, SF, etc).

My concern is just about decreasing output size.

Comment: I believe fonts are tree-shaken in release builds as of a recent release of flutter.

Comment: All unused fonts will be ignored when you want to release your app